# PHP I need to summarize odd and even numbers in table

Tags: php

I was wondering how to summarize odd and even numbers in table, in one column even numbers, and other columns odd numbers.

My code right now:

```
<?php
$number = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

echo "<style>table{border-collapse:collapse;}</style>";
echo "<table border ='1px'; >";
echo "<tr>
      <th>EVEN NUMBERS</th>
      <th>ODD NUMBERS</th>
  </tr>";

  for ($i=0; $i < count($number); $i++) { 
      echo "<tr>";
    if ($number[$i] % 2 == 0) {
      echo " <td>$number[$i] </td>";

      }
      else {
        echo "<td><b>$number[$i]</b></td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }


 echo "</table>";           
?>
```

Comment: What result does your code produce?  In what way is that result incorrect?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: I get my table, in one column and in another there are only even numbers, and no odd numbers.I don't know how to put odd numbers in second column

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can find out how to [ask] to provide enough information to allow people to answer and help.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean.  The output would only produce one column because each iteration of the loop produces a single-column row, regardless of the result.  You can add empty columns into your `echo` statements (for example: `echo "<td>$number[$i]</td><td></td>";`)  That would produce two columns, but with staggered values and empty cells.  You may need to re-think the logic a bit.  Perhaps first divide the array into even and odd arrays, then loop through both arrays simultaneously to output the values.  There may likely be other ways to do it too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase $i by 2 and get rid of the if statement. That is something like this:

```
<?php
$number = array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

echo "<style>table{border-collapse:collapse;}</style>";
echo "<table border ='1px'; >";
echo "<tr>
      <th>EVEN NUMBERS</th>
      <th>ODD NUMBERS</th>
  </tr>";
for ($i=0; $i < count($number); $i+= 2) { 
      echo "<tr>";
      echo " <td>$number[$i] </td>";
      $j = $i+1;
      echo "<td><b>$number[$j]</b></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```